# Strophe.js: checking internet connection

Tags: javascript, ejabberd, strophe

I want to do a background check, which will be every minute to check the Internet connection. If it interrupted then I show a message and try to reconnect. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want to implement XMPP Ping ([XEP-0199](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0199.html)).

There is a Strophe plugin for this:
https://github.com/strophe/strophejs-plugins/tree/master/ping

You ping the server, and then provide a callback for a successful response and a callback for when an error occurs or when the timeout was reached.

```

```
connection.ping.ping(
    "serviceJID@server.org",
    success_callback,
    error_callback,
    timeout
);
```

```

In the `error_callback` you can determine if timeout was reached and then reconnect to your XMPP server.

Comment: Hi, i am wondering the ping plugin, can i use it to ping any users/JID? I am trying to use it to ping the message recipient to see if the person is connected, and if the recipient isnt online i trigger another script.

Comment: Yes, you can also ping clients (i.e. JIDs) and not just servers.

Comment: Hi, its been a few months, but i am wondering if i ping a client(JID) would i need the SID, the session id? like jid@server.org/sid??? Or just jid@server.org is ok? Because i tried pinging without the SID, and the "receiver" isnt getting anything.